# Can I upload a HUAWEI router config file with encrypted data?

Tags: encryption, hash, passwords, router

I am trying to get full access to my router ONT, a HUAWEI K562e.

After messing around with the hidden options of my router I got to download a config file in XML that shows me a hashed password for admin and superadmin. These hasehs can't be decrypted afaik as they are salted.

I know the password for admin, I have the hash, and the salt, but somehow I am unable to get the password from it so I guess I should give up trying to decypher the superadmin one.
Therefore, following some stuff I saw on the web, it seems that if I modify these lines I could change the router login details to whatever I want.

My issue is that the whole .xml config file is filled with hashes.
Here's my question: if I upload this xml config file, even without changes... will I mess up my router configuration?

I can't request a restore to the ISP without contacting my landlord, so I am pretty much handcuffed as I don't want to try and see what happens...